# Static IP address over different wifi access points

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, debian, ipv4

I'm setting up a headless PC in order for it to be accessible using ssh (over wifi) only, it has LMDE5 (a Debian based flavor of Linux Mint).

On one hand, setting a static IP address will give me the ability to connect to that PC from any other PC at home, even from my smartphones (via termux).
On the other hand, as I'm using different phones as access point for my home LAN, I cannot configure the PC with a static IP, because this would bring also a fixed gateway/primaryDNS (which will be the phone) which is going to vary due to the phone I will be using.

(the wifi interface wlp5s0 is already set to connect to any of the phones SSIDs with the proper key)

I see Android hot spot is set for a subnet like 192.168.43.x and I wish my new PC to have address 192.168.43.201

Now, the solution I found is changing the IPv4 after the connection is set up, so I leave dhcp do its job, then change the address.
To achieve this, into /etc/if-up.d/ I have this simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ "$IFACE" == "wlp5s0" ] || exit 0

ifconfig wlp5s0 192.168.43.201/24
```

which always sets the proper IPv4 address (after the network connection is up), but the whole thing doesn't always work - it only works when the phone sets its own gateway address as 192.168.43.1 (then I can check the repo for updates, "ping 192.168.43.201" works from other PCs and ssh connects) other cases won't work (no internet access).
The working cases show an output for "ip route show", otherwise the command gives nothing at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Writing down my solution as it can be useful for others.

I couldn't have full control of my network settings until I realized who really is in charge of any network related setup, that is NetworkManager. I switched to nmcli in order to change the IPv4 address and that's all. My script became:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" != "wlp5s0" ]
then
    exit 0
fi

nmcli device modify wlp5s0 ipv4.addresses 192.168.43.201/24
```

and indeed the modification works 100% of times (no concerns about gateway).

Please note: nmcli **does not change** the current address, instead it **adds a new address** to the same network interface. In fact:

```
$ nmcli
wlp5s0: collegato to ***my_network***
        "Intel 6 AX200"
        wifi (iwlwifi), ***my_mac_address***, hw, mtu 1500
        predefinito ip4
        inet4 192.168.43.201/24
        inet4 192.168.43.237/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.43.0/24
        route4 192.168.43.0/24
        inet6 fe80::32fe:afc2:a611:527e/64
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ff00::/8
```

where two ipv4 addresses are used for the same wireless interface (and they both work).