# Linux set IP address dependend on SSID name

Tags: linux, dhcp, wifi-configuration, static-ip, ssid

I would like to set the IP address configuration in my `/etc/network/interfaces` based on the SSID. Wifi connection is configured via wpa_supplicant and has two `network={...}` blocks with different SSIDs.

Example:
IF the SSID is "network1", then the IP address should be set as static, like:

```
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.14
...
```

If the SSID is "network2", then the IP should be set with DHCP, like:

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
...
```

Is this possible, and when yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1730736/static-ip-address-over-different-wifi-access-points) help ?

Comment: @harrymc, yes that is helpful. But I have an additional requirement:
I need to set different IP settings per SSID. Not always the same static IP.
So, I need to enhance the "decision-tree" which IP setup to choose by a test which SSID I'm connected to. For now I have no clue how to do it, but will dig deeper...

Comment: The bash script can be modified to handle multiple IPs. Study it.